# Please help me to find this 80's-90's rock song

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

I don't remember the name of a song I heard some time ago, but I remember the video of this one.

All starts in a wedding where the groom starts noticing strange things in the guests at some point they all start turning into monsters and the groom tries to escape.

My mother told me this song was released in 80's-90's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you thinking of ["Jeopardy"](https://youtu.be/yAJNwPWVmNc) by The Greg Kihn Band, 1983

Comment: Wow seriously thanks, this song brings me so many childhood memories so many thanks.